# GSheets: ArrayFormula & Sumifs don't drag

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, sumifs

I tried to use `ARRAYFORMULA` with `SUMIFS`, but the result only catches the very first line and drags it down for all rows.

I can't figure out how to make it work. The only solution I thought of was to write script that would automatically autofill the formula of the sumifs.

My formula is like this:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(if(**B2:B15**<>"",sumifs(Downloads!$A:$A,Downloads!$B:$B,**B2:B15**,Downloads!$E:$E,'parameters for graph'!$C$3),""))

Here is the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KSsMIbV7p3OIhJOvd7mfpi8l490NOY-aS3zXdG0746Q/edit?usp=sharing).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it:

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula
(--(Downloads!B2:B=transpose(filter(B2:B15,B2:B15<>"")))*
--(Downloads!E2:E='parameters for graph'!C3))),ARRAYFORMULA(Downloads!A2:A*1))
```

[your example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jQGWzvq4ZSP6JYPp2k7ZO1QYZG8uqc4MSuLXD2pJ6d0/edit?usp=sharing)